# Prevent click-Event on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, dom-events

I am developing a PhoneGap-App for iPad. On one screen you have to fill out a form with about 20 textfields. As input-fields only react to the click-event (which have this not long but yet annoying delay) I tried the following:

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type=number], input[type=date], input[type="tel"], input[type=password], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], textarea, select').live("touchend", function(e) {
    if(!swipe) {
        $(this).focus();
    }
    swipe = false;
    return false;
});
```

(I check for swipe in the `touchmove` event)

This works, but now I want to prevent the original click event on the inputs.
The problem is, when I activate an input-field with the `.focus()` method, the keyboard pops up and slides the page a little bit up AND then the `click` event gets fired and activates another input-field a little bit below my desired input.

For preventing click I already tried:

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type=number], input[type=date], input[type="tel"], input[type=password], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], textarea, select').live("click", function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

but this also doesn't work :(

Is there another trick to activate input-fields immediately after I touched it without any delay?

Comment: it's been a year.. you should specify the right answer

Answer (score 4):

you can try this

```
 $('input, textarea, select').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: append new element not click function :) is live("click") change.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use preventDefault to prevent the default action:

```
  $('input[type="text"], input[type=number], input[type=date], input[type="tel"], input[type=password], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], textarea, select').live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

It is stop propagation.

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type=number], input[type=date], input[type="tel"], input[type=password], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], textarea, select').live("click", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue as you and tried to implement all of the other solutions posted and found that none of them completely worked for me. Instead, I borrowed ideas from all of the prior solutions and found that this snippet of code solved my problem.

```
    $('input, textarea, select').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```